# Solving asymptotic complexity of a recurrence relation by induction

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I am asked to solve the following recurrence relation by what we call "substitution" in my class, where you assume a solution, and then show that it is true by induction.
I have 
$$t(n) = 2t(n/2) + 1$$ I have shown by other methods that this is $\mathcal{O}(n)$ and for this method, I do the following:

Assume $t(n) = \mathcal{O}(n)$ then given $t(n/2) \leq cn/2$ we want to show that $t(n) \leq cn$. Note that this has to be the $same$ $c$. I have used this method to prove other recurrence relations. However, for some reason, my algorithms prof told me that this one needs some kind of trick... I have checked Cormen's (he said there is an example in there) and can't find anything in the relevant section. Here is an example of how such a proof works for another example.

---

$$t(n) = 2t(n/2) + n\log(n)$$
Since we know that the recurrence relation for mergesort is given by $t(n) = 2t(n/2) + n$ has the solution $t(n) = \mathcal{O}(n\log n)$, we might assume that $t(n) = 2t(n/2) + n\log(n)$ has the solution $t(n) = \mathcal{O}(n\log^2(n))$. We will attempt to show this by substitution.
    \begin{align*}
 t(n) &= 2t(n/2) + n\log n \\
 \mathrm{guess }\ t(n) &= \mathcal{O}(n\log^2n) \\
 \mathrm{assume }\ t(n/2) &\leq c(n/2)log^2(n/2) \\
 \mathrm{show} \ t(n) &\leq cn\log^2(n) \\
 t(n) &= 2t(n/2) + n\log n \\
 t(n) &\leq 2(c(n/2)\log^2(n/2)) + n\log n \\
    &= cn(\log^2n - 2\log(n)\log(2) + \log^2n) + n\log n \\
    &= cn\log^2n -cn(\log(n)\log(2) -\log^2(2)) + n\log n
 \end{align*}
    Recall that we wanted to show $$t(n) \leq cn\log^2n$$ so we get
    \begin{align*}
 cn\log^2n-cn(\log(n)\log(2)-log^2(2)) + n\log n &\leq cn\log^2n \\
 cn(\log(n)\log(2) - log^2(2)) &\geq n\log n
 \end{align*}
    Which is true for sufficiently large $c$.

---

Attempting such a solution here gives the following problem:
Let us make a conjecture that $t(n)$ is $\mathcal{O}(n)$. Then we will try to prove this by induction.\
We begin by assuming that by the definition of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ that $t(n/2) \leq cn/2$. Then we need to show that $t(n) \leq cn$.
\begin{align*}
 t(n) &=2t(n/2) + 1 \\
 t(n) &\leq 2(cn/2) + 1 \\
 &=cn + 1
\end{align*}
we want to show that $t(n) \leq cn$ so we get 
$$cn+1 \leq cn$$

This is obviously a contradiction. Does anyone know how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove that $t(n) \leq \frac{1}{2} c n+n-1$

So $t(n)\leq 2t(n/2)+1 \leq 2(\frac{1}{2}c n/2+n/2-1)+1= \frac{1}{2}c n+n-2+1= \frac{1}{2}c n+n-1$.

And then its easy to prove that $t(n) \leq \frac{1}{2}c n +n-1 \leq c n$

Whenever $c\geq2$, since its $O(n)$ we can put $c>2$.

Comment: You can't just say "try to prove x" and then use x in your argument for the proof. You subbed in t(n/2) <= 1/2(cn/2) + n/2 -1 But that is what you are trying to show.

Comment: i did skip the induction assumption, which is assume that $t(n/2) \leq \frac{1}{2} c \frac{n}{2}+ \frac{n}{2}-1$ prove that $t(n) \leq \frac{1}{2} c n+n-1$,